# Get a row from a table

Tags: jquery, html-table, row

I need to retrieve a row from a table using jQuery. My row looks like this:

```
",XX-PowerSib-C</td><td>No</td><td>4</td><td>4</td><td>Yes</td><td>Yes</td><td></td>"
```

I need to separate these values.

```
function UpdateRow(Updatelink) {
  debugger;

  var row = Updatelink.parentNode.parentNode;
  var value1 = row.innerHTML;
  value1 = value1.replace("<td>", ",");
  document.getElementById("Update_PartId").value = value1;
}
```

Comment: This is really confusing. Can you elaborate and paste in your HTML as well?

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to read the table with jQuery and then you can read the rows from the table. You have not given your table details, so I am giving sample example:

```js
table = $('#yourtableid').DataTable(); // optional

var rows = [];
rows = $("#yourtableid").find("tbody tr");
if (rows.length > 0) {
  $.each(rows, function(index, value) {
    var rowData = {};
    var comments = value.children[2].innerText; // here 2 is your column position
  });
}
```